# Weak* sequentiality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Suppose we are given a Banach space $E$ such that weak* compact subsets of $E^*$ are weak* sequentially compact (for example this happens when $E$ is separable). Does it follow that if $A$ is a subset of $E^*$ and $f\in \overline{A}^{w^*}$ then $f$ is actually a limit of a **sequence** from $A$? If not, is there a countable set $B\subset A$ such that $f\in \overline{B}^{w^*}$?

Comment: In $\ell_2$, let $A$ be the set of all vectors of the form $e_m+m e_n$, $m<n$. Then $0$ is in the weak (weak*) closure of $A$ but no sequence from $A$ converges to $0$ weakly (or weak*).

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample given by David Mitra is described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433725/how-to-show-0-is-a-point-of-closure-of-weak-topology-but-not-a-limit-of-weakl/433737). Another type of counterexample is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42337/on-the-weak-closure) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231176/weak-closure-of-sqrt-n-e-nn-in-mathbb-n-and-metrizability-of-weak-topol?rq=1) and more generally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190226/on-weak-closure-again/190279#190279).